# What are these node js variables at the of the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am creating an API with NodeJS, Express and PassportJS but I think this is a JavaScript question.

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false },

    function (err, user, info) {
        if (user === false) {
            res.send('ko');
        } else {
            res.send('ok');
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

My question is:

Why is `(req, res, next)` after the authenticate function? Is it related with the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the function `password.authenticate` returns a function/closure. The code is like

```
foo(x, y)(z);
```

i.e. the function returned by the call `foo(x, y)` is called with parameter `z`.

A very simple example is

```
function multiplier(k) {
    return function(x) { return x*k; };
}

console.log(multiplier(7)(6)); // outputs 42
```

Answer (score 0):

The `()` call the function. The variables inside it are passed to it as arguments. You can see them coming into the containing function on line one of your code.